# SAM creates new version of lambda layer every time even if there is no change

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, aws-lambda-layers, sam

I have a Gitlab CI pipeline which triggers AWS SAM template. This created a lambda layer. But though I do not make any change to lambda layer and re-trigger the Gitlab CI pipeline, a new version of AWS lambda layer gets created again. I need to stop creation of new version of lambda layer when there is no change made to lambda layer. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Below are my files (just included relevant sections)

**my SAM template:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 15

Resources:

  MyLambdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:      
      LayerName: 'my-lambda-layer'
      ContentUri: layers/my-lambda-layer-code
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.7   

  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'my-aws-lambda'
      CodeUri: my-aws-lambda/
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 300
      EventInvokeConfig:
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 0
        MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 100     
      Layers:          
        - !Ref MyLambdaLayer
```

**Gitlab-ci file:**

```
- echo "creating services"    
- sam build --template-file samtemplate.yaml
- sam package --template-file samtemplate.yaml --output-template-file output.yaml --s3-bucket $S3REPOBUCKET
- sam deploy --template-file output.yaml --stack-name $STACKNAME --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --on-failure ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Well, can we see the pipeline? How can we help with no code? 

Comment: Hi Ermiya, Sorry. I thought this was a general env issue needing no code references :) . I have included the code snippets now :)  Thanks for checking!

Comment: Are you using any persistent storage for your gitlab ci? You could possibly look into SAM's option to cache builds (`--cached`) along with `--cache-dir`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html

Comment: Does absolutely nothing change? Can you use `git` or another tool to confirm that *nothing* is really changed?

Comment: Yes Ermiya Eskandary. Nothing changes in Git. I have 7 layers and new versions for all 7 layers gets created in AWS every time I build the pipeline.